# Updating a TextView with a SeekBar's value (ultra-slow)

Tags: android, textview, seekbar

Now look at that! I am having trouble with one of the simplest goals: updating a plain TextView with the value of a SeekBar.

This is my approach:

```
    @Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    if (fromUser) {
        mInfoText.setText(mFunction.getUserFriendlyString(progress));
    }
}
```

It basically works, but it kind of blocks the whole UI when I'm dragging. (Note: I tried both View.post() and Activity.runOnUiThread()).

Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are taking way too long to get the userFriendlyString.  Are you using String.Format and/or loading a string resource?  String.Format takes a LOT longer than you think.

One thing you could do is run method profiling from DDMS and see what is actually taking up that time.  See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html

Comment: I'll give TraceView a shot. (It was not the userFriendlyString - but thanks anyway!)

Answer (score 0):

I have very similar stuff, but everything works like a charm. Maybe something wrong with your `mFunction.getUserFriendlyString` ?